# Itemdatabound event of longlistselector control in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to control the visibility of an image (inside a dynamically bind longlistselector control), depending on a binding value (say if somevalue>0 then make that image visible otherwise invisible).But there is no such event like itemdatabound in the longlistselector to accomplish this task,  I am  new to windows phone development, and really don't have an idea how to do this.Please help me guys.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

```
public class BoolToVisiblityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value
            ? Visibility.Collapsed
            : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to achieve this would be to bind the visibility property of the Image to a property on your bound data object. Often, the property on the data would be a boolean and a converter would be used to convert the boolean to a Visibility enum value. E.g.,

```
<Image Visibility = {Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource myBoolToVisibilityConverter} />
```

[See binding with converters example](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Talking-about-Converters-in-WP7--Coding4fun-toolkit-converters-in-depth)